# How Does the VS 2010 web.config work?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010

I am just wondering in VS2010 the web.config is broken up into

```
web.config
web.debug.config
web.release.config
```

So from what I gathered is the web.config is just like the master template. So I am guessing in my debug I could put things like my local database where in my release one I would put my server database.

Now how does it know when to use the release version or debug version?

I also here that you can have more than 2. How does that work?

Comment: the key phrase to search for is 'web.config transformation' - a good starting point is @ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VS will use the debug version if you publish/run with the Debug configuration, and will use the Release version if you publish/run with the Release configuration.  Also, if you add more build configurations, you can have web.config versions for each of those build configurations as well.

Comment: How do you make more build configurations?

Comment: Right-click your solution, select Configuration Manager. Select "New" from the Active solution configuration, use Debug or Release to copy from, give it a name. Once you've done this, you can manually add Web.[ConfigName].config or right click web.config again and select "Add Config Transforms".